# Multi-label compute class weight - unhashable type

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, scikit-learn

Working in a ***multi-label*** classification problem with *13 possibles outputs* in my neural network with Keras, sklearn, etc...

Each output can be an array like [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,0].

I have an imbalance dataset and i trying to apply compute_class_weight method, like:

```
class_weight = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(Y_train), Y_train)
```

When i try to run my code, i got ***Unhashable Type: 'numpy.ndarray':***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 115, in <module>
   train(dataset, labels)
 File "main.py", line 66, in train
   class_weight = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(Y_train), Y_train)
 File "/home/python-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py", line 41, in compute_class_weight
  if set(y) - set(classes):
  TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I know that is because i working with arrays, already tried add some dict,

i.e.:

```
class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(np.unique(y_train), class_weight))
```

Well, i don't know what to do, tried others strategies, but no success... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing this error because your Y_train data is a 2d array, where compute_class_weights [expects a 1d array](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html#).

compute_class_weights can be used for multiclass classifications, but apparently not multi-label problems like yours.

You could try using [compute_sample_weight](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight.html) instead, which is slightly different but handles multi-label output problems such as this.